# How do I assign a value to a ComboBox from a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview and I want to fill a combobox from one of its cells.
I tried this but it does not work.

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Note combobox is not in the datadgrid; it's external to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
comboBox1.SelectedText = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

if Datagrid's column[1] contains value member and combo box is also bind with value and display member than you can use

```
comboBox1.SelectedValue  = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: How does SelectedText work if the ComboBox.DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList?

Answer (score 1):

Use `comboBox1.SelectedText` property instead.

Answer (score 1):

About **ComboBox.SelectedText** Property on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx):

> **Gets or sets the text that is selected in the *editable portion* of a ComboBox**.

If your ComboBox items are strings, the following line should be enough:

```
 ComboBox1.SelectedItem = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim();
```

Please mind that the casing of the string in the DataGridView cell must match the casing of ComboBox string item in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmb1.SelectedText = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["cellName"].Value);
```

Or try this

```
cmb1.SelectedValue  = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["cellName"].Value);
```